# Android 10 keeps killing app in background

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

i created an app to automatically save contacts for my friend on his whatsapp using cordova. The app has to work in background so i also added [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode). on my android 5.0, it works fine. but while testing on android 10 which is what my friend uses. the OS kills the app after few minutes(sometimes seconds) of being in background.

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

i also did this in my code

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.openBatteryOptimizationsSettings();
```

My guess is, there is another permission i need to work in background on Android 10.

Comment: Possibly related: [Android 10 start activity from background not working, foreground() and unlock() not working](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/499) or [Android 9 don't work](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/493). It may help to review the list of related open issues: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+android+background